# Upload application/octet-stream (image JPG - Spring Multipart post Request)

Tags: spring, image, file-upload, format, ionic4

#### I'm trying to **store images (jpg)** on ​​my server through a mobile application

I take an image with the ionic camera (CameraPreview) and pass them to the Back service (Spring) through a post http method.

> The problem is the format. The images are stored correctly but without any **format**.

This is the Camera Code to **take the picture**:

```
 takePicture() {
    this.cameraPreview.takePicture(this.pictureOpts).then((imageData) => {
     this.selectedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.globalDataService.changePictureTaken(this.selectedImage);
      this.location.back();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.selectedImage = 'assets/img/test.jpg';
    });
  }
```

this is the code that **sends the image to the server**:

```
uploadImageService(url: string, param: any) {
    const fd: FormData = new FormData();
    const imgBlob = new Blob([param],{type: param.type});
    fd.append('file', imgBlob);
     return this.http
       .post(url, fd, httpOptionsImages);
  }
```

This is the server-side code:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/subir-imagen")
    public ResponseEntity handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException, SQLException {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "/subir-imagen, handleFileUpload file.tostring {0}", file.toString());
 String fileName = fileManagerService.storeFile(file);
 String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString()
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fileDownloadUri);
}

public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) throws SQLException, IOException {
        // Normalize file name
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getName());
        try {
            // Check if the file's name contains invalid characters
            if (fileName.contains("..")) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence {0}", fileName);
            }
            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
            Path path = Paths.get(fileStoragePath + File.separator + fileName + "." + extension.toLowerCase());
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
       } 
       catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Could not store file " + fileName + ". Please try again! {0}", ex);
       }
    return fileName;
}
```

When I make the post request through Postman, the image is stored in the correct format and when it is downloaded, the image is displayed correctly.

When I make the request through the application, the image is stored correctly in the server, but without extension, I try to put the format by hand but it can not be displayed.

When I run in the server side `file.getContentType());` I have seen that the image sent by my application is of type **application/octet-stream** and the image sent by postman is **image/jpg**

I tried to convert the application/octet-stream to image/jpg without success in java.
Also I Tried to put `Content-Type`headers to the request, but I've only got some errors...

I have also tried to pass the image directly through the form, without blob, and also without blob or form, and it still does not work.

Is there any way of when you copy the file, you pass it to a concrete form?
or any way to format this image from the ionic camera?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "without format", do you simply mean without the file extension (e.g., jpg) in the filename, or something else?

Comment: @peekay the images are saved without extension, (.jpg, .png ...) but it is as if they did not have any format. If I give them a .png or .jpg format manually, the photo viewer does not read them and shows an error, as if they were not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are two separate issues here.  The image data returned is *base64 encoded* JPEG, which is suitable for a web view when prepended with `data:image/jpeg;base64,`.  But normal picture viewers (and most other applications) expect *binary* JPEG (not base64 encoded), and without the `data:image` tag prepended.

We can check by opening the file on the server (with a hex or text editor) to see if it is base64 encoded.  A binary JPEG can be identified by having the string 'JFIF' near the beginning of the file.

If so, the first thing to try is to convert the base64 image to binary format (without the 'data:image') before sending it to the server. Or we can also convert server side.  With Javascript there's the `atob()` function, while on the server Java 8 has a Base64 library. There's a coder/decoder (codec) from Apache Commons as well.

The file extension can be solved by specifying a full filename to `fd.append()`.

Comment: I have tried to remove data: image of the image, the image is not shown in the application and still not saved correctly.
Can you better explain what you mean by atob () or coder / decoder?

Comment: There are two different file formats (encodings) a JPEG image can be represented in.  The first is _binary_ encoding, the second is _base64_ encoding.   (Base64 is also called "text" encoding.) .  Your application requires base64 encoding (plus the "data: image" etc. tag).  But most other applications (picture viewers, photoshop, etc.) require the original binary encoding.   Since there are two different encodings required for different purposes, you can use functions such as atob() / btoa() in Javascript or the Java/Apache equivalents to convert between them.

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding for additional conversion options (such as into buffer arrays).